# Keras model.predict - argmax always outputs 0 (seq2seq model)

Tags: nlp, deep-learning, keras, recurrent-neural-network, argmax

I am working with the spelling bees code and applying it to a similar seq2seq task. I am struggling with the predition and the output of the argmax function. For some reason the output of the argmax returns only 0 for any case.

I have changed a lot of parameters, chose other axis .. But nothing seems to work. I would be grateful for any clue!

I have

```
parms = {'verbose': 2}

lstm_params = {}


def get_rnn(return_sequences= True): 
    return LSTM(dim, return_sequences=return_sequences, recurrent_dropout=0.2, implementation=1, dropout=0.2)



inp = Input((maxlen_p,))
x = Embedding(input_vocab_size, 60)(inp)

x = Bidirectional(get_rnn())(x)
x = get_rnn(False)(x)

x = RepeatVector(maxlen)(x)
x = get_rnn()(x)
x = get_rnn()(x)
x = TimeDistributed(Dense(output_vocab_size, activation='softmax'))(x)


model = Model(inp, x)

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='Adam', metrics=['acc'])

hist=model.fit(input_train, np.expand_dims(labels_train,-1), 
          validation_data=[input_test, np.expand_dims(labels_test,-1)], 
          batch_size=128, **parms, epochs=3)

SVG(model_to_dot(model).create(prog='dot', format='svg'))
```

In this function, there is this problem:

```
def eval_keras(input):

    preds = model.predict(input, batch_size=128)
    predict = np.argmax(preds, axis = 2) 
    return (np.mean([all(real==p) for real, p in zip(labels_test, predict)]), predict)
```

**preds:**

```
[[[9.1350e-02 4.3054e-04 7.0428e-04 ... 5.0601e-04 7.1275e-04 5.8476e-03]
  [5.9895e-01 3.5628e-05 7.1672e-05 ... 4.2559e-05 7.7454e-05 3.3954e-03]
  [7.2249e-01 1.6146e-05 3.3864e-05 ... 2.0008e-05 3.8247e-05 2.3551e-03] ...
```

**predict:**

```
[[0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 ...
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]
 [0 0 0 ... 0 0 0]]
```

**real (value):**

```
[ 24 360  60  80 585  73 706 595 766 625 240 284   8   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, your class is highly unbalanced. Try to use `class_weights` in order to compensate the fact that majority of your examples is equal to `0`.